# Enable to read file or reach on path location

Tags: java, server

I am hitting an API on server and getting the response as

```
Content-Length: 313471Content-Type: binary/octet-streamContent-disposition: attachment;filename=System_log-NAS-usb-20170224-122526.zipPK
```

I am not able to  read its stream or get its path from where I have to download it.Can anyone have an idea about that.

Comment: Have you tried to download from (assuming it's http) `http://server/System_log-NAS-usb-20170224-122526.zip`? Or add some more information what you did to get the above message and what you tried to download the file and how it failed.

Comment: site can't be reached.
On postman, we are getting only this response.So how can I reach to the file??

Comment: With this little information, you provide, it's really not possible to help.